# Loop terminating program prematurely

Tags: c

this loop leads to unexpected termination of program. 
please help me to identify the problem.

```
char n1, n2;
int wt, edges;    

printf("\nEnter the Number of edges in the Network\n");
scanf("%d",&edges);
printf("Enter the details of all the edges of the Network\n"); 
 for(int i=0;i<edges;i++)
 {
    printf("\nedge - %d : ",i+1);

    printf("\n n1 = ");
    scanf("%s", &n1);
    n1 = toupper(n1);
    printf("\n n2 = ");
    scanf("%s", &n2);
    n2 = toupper(n1);
    printf("\n wt = ");
    scanf("%d", &wt);
    int n11 = n1 - 'A' ;
    int n22 = n2 - 'A';
    w[n11][n22]=w[n22][n11]=wt;
 }
```

sample input :
      n1 = a
      n2 = b
      wt  = 1

toupper() will change the input to uppercase letter.

Comment: You have to show more code, namely, the declaration of `i`, `edges`, `w`, etc. And what is `toupper()`? What's the input?

Comment: Please post the complete program which compiles. Please state the sample input and the expected output. Please state what your program writes instead.

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &n1);` ditto. and `n2 = toupper(n2);`

Comment: Please check that every `scanf` call returns `1`. If it returns something else, then abort with an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's the problem identified by BLUEPIXY. This is wrong:

```
char n1;
scanf("%s", &n1);
```

One possible solution:

```
char n1;
scanf(" %c", &n1);
```

Another possible solution, which allows any whitespace (not only a single space) between words:

```
char n1;
char tmp[128];
if (scanf("%s", tmp) != 1) abort();
if (strlen(tmp) != 1) abort();
n1 = tmp[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to input a string into a `char` variable. Even if you enter one character, the next memory position is overwritten with `\0`. This may access read-only memory and results in the abrupt termination.

Instead do:

```
scanf(" %c", &n1);
```